# Print fetch result horizontally on 3 column

Tags: html, database, alignment, fetch, tabular

I have some data on my db and I'm printing those to screen vertically but I want to print them on three different column. They can be in div, table etc.

For two column I found a solution.

```
If current row is even number, print location A 

else location B
```

but if we want to print to more than two column how can we do that?

For example input must like that..

Name1 | Name2 | Name3

Name4 | Name5 | Name6

..... | ..... | .....

Comment: what is the problem using table? using `td` will put the data in columns

Comment: but it is printing vertically to table not horizontally. this is php side html side is very simple. I think we will use mod

Answer (score 0):

This way is much better than the previous I suggested. Took me a while to find it, but I knew I had done it somewhere!

```
echo '<table><tr>';
for ($i=0; $i < 40; $i++) { 
     foreach ($data as $el) {
        echo '<td>' . $el . '</td>';
      if ($i++ > 1 && $i++ % 3 == 0 ) echo '</tr><tr>';
     }
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```